# acceder a puntero triple

Tags: c

como puedo asignarle una estructura a un puntero void que apunta a una matriz dinamica de tipo void y queria saber de que forma puedo acceder a una pocicion "x" y asignarle una estructura o tomar una dato de esa estructura

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include "Tierra.h"
#include "Tablero.h"
#include "Bomba.h"

void*** tablero;

void IniciarTablero(int n) {
    tablero = (void ***)malloc(sizeof(void **));
    tablero[0] = (void **)malloc(sizeof(void *) * n);
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        tablero[0][i] = (void *)malloc(sizeof(void));
    }
}
```

en este codigo creo un puntero void y le asigno una matriz void pero no se como asignar una estructura en una parte [i][j] de la matriz o si le asigne una estructura como acceder a los datos de la estructura

Comment: La pregunta no es clara. `void*` es un tipo incompleto. Puedes utilizarlo con el fin de guardar una dirección de memoria pero no puedes desreferenciarlo. Necesitas convertirlo en un puntero de otro tipo para eso.